# How to get logged in username in WCM JSP component page

Tags: websphere-portal, wcm

I need to know if there is a way to get the logged in username in WCM JSP component in IBM Websphere Portal 8. I dont even know where to begin looking for this solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you can get current username via

```
request.getUserPrincipal().getName()
```

You can use Puma api as well to get more detailed user information.

**Example**

http://blog.manishchhabra.com/2011/05/ibm-portal-user-management-architecture-puma-spi/

**Javadoc**

http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/dw/lotus/portal_javadoc/80/portal/spi_docs/index.html